# Hazelcast offset Predicate

Tags: java, offset, hazelcast, in-memory-database, hazelcast-imap

In Hazelcast, has been implemented `PagingPredicate` which helps to get data page by page.

Is there any possibility to get data with offset and limit? (Not page by page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find better solution then 
calculate and get two pages using PagingPredicate and 
get sub list from this result to get data with offset and limit like in SQL databases.

Method example:

```
public Set<M> findOffsetValues(int offset,int limit) {
    PagingPredicate pagingPredicate = new PagingPredicate<>(getDefaultComporator(), limit);
    pagingPredicate.setPage(offset / limit);
    List<M> page = new ArrayList<>(itemsCacheMap.values(pagePredicate));
    pagePredicate.nextPage();
    page.addAll(itemsCacheMap.values(pagePredicate));
    int startIndex = offset % limit;
    return new LinkedHashSet<>(CollectionUtil.saveSublist(page, startIndex, startIndex + limit));
}
```

Utility method **CollectionUtil.saveSublist**

```
public static <E> List<E> saveSublist(List<E> list, int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    int checkedFromIndex = list.size() == 0
                           ? 0
                           : fromIndex >= list.size() ? list.size() - 1 : fromIndex;
    int checkedToIndex = toIndex > list.size() ? list.size() : toIndex;
    return list.subList(checkedFromIndex, checkedToIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [BetweenPredicate](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10/javadoc/com/hazelcast/query/impl/predicates/BetweenPredicate.html) which would achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: No. I need to get Sorted data with offset like in SQL databases. 
This predicate helps to gather data Between two comparable items

Comment: you can use `SqlPredicate` but that could be inefficient. If it is map, you can add ordered index on the field you need sorting on.